# Asterisk Softphone

Tags: asterisk, asteriskami

I would like to create softphone similar to XLite, which is so much good to interact with asterisk. I have gone through the tutorial about asterisk java, briefing about AMI and Fast AGI scripts.But it didn't workout as per my expectation.My first preparation was to make call from  one extension to another using asterisk java. At Fast AGI script, I don't know how to perform continues audio streaming is happened. In my second preparation, I tried with JAIN SIP for user agent authentication as log in and used JMF for audio streaming. But this streaming process is happening through peer to peer. Using AMI and Fast AGI script, it is possible to create softphone? or I need to depend other libraries like JAIN SIP and JMF?

Answer (score 2):

You can create web based softphones with sipml5 and sip.js

Answer (score 0):

AMI and FastAGI is technology to control server(asterisk)

You need SDK to create client. You are gooing wrong direction. Check libiax for java or opensource softphones already created by smart people.

Answer (score 0):

Please use [PJSIP Library](http://www.pjsip.org/) for creating soft-phone. This library gives all functionlities as per your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Web-Phone with WebRTC. There are a lot of source codes out there today. Here is the link: https://webrtc.org/start/ 
With WebRTC, you can create a softphone on the server and from there, you make call anywhere. 
If you have more questions, please let me know!